# Grails cant use Spock framework?

Tags: testing, grails, spock

I am currently working on a project that had started with no TDD in place and now I have taken the following steps to start using Spock for Unit and Integration testing on this project:

1. Added the following to the **buildconfig**:

   test ":spock:0.7"
2. Then created a spec at **"test/unit/MYCLASSNAME"** called **MyfunctionControllerSpec** as shown below:

   ```
   import grails.test.mixin.*
   import spock.lang.Specification

   class MyfunctionControllerSpec extends Specification {

       void "list() should return no results with no records in DB"() {
           given:
               def model = controller.list()
           expect:
               model.taskInstanceList.size() == 0
               model.taskInstanceTotal == 0
       }

   }
   ```

However I am getting the following errors with the Specification import line:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification
```

I don’t understand what I am doing wrong, have I imported or install Spock wrong?

Thanks in advance

---

*EDIT********

---

I have tried the suggestion below and then the solution wont run and it still doesnt recognise the Specification class, even when I start typing "inport spo" and press cntrl+space nothing comes up as if it cant even recogise the plugin either:

```
Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: spock-grails-support-0.7-groovy-2.0.pom.sha1
| Downloading: spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.pom.sha1
| Downloading: spock-grails-support-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar.sha1
| Downloading: spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar.sha1.
| Environment set to development....
| Error Error loading event script from file [/media/system/workspace/sms_bskyb_New_V2(Dynam Messages)/plugins/tool-ui/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/system/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Error loading event script from file [/home/system/.grails/2.1.0/projects/sms_bskyb/plugins/database-migration-1.1/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/system/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Error loading event script from file [/home/system/.grails/2.1.0/projects/sms_bskyb/plugins/tomcat-2.1.0/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/system/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Error loading event script from file [/home/system/.grails/2.1.0/projects/sms_bskyb/plugins/spock-0.7/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/system/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Error loading event script from file [/home/system/.grails/2.1.0/projects/sms_bskyb/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/system/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/system/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
1 error
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Grails 2.1.0 whereas Groovy 2.0 was introduced in Grails 2.2.0 and above. Hopefully you **do not** need to explicit dependency `org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0`. Only use as below:

```
plugins{
    test ":spock:0.7"
}
```

In case you still find an issue then isolate the problem by creating a fresh new bare bone grails app and install the plugin as mentioned in the plugin docs. Try to see if there is any classpath clash. If the problem still exists, then clear `ivy-cache` and/or `.m2` and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I almost answered this here, but I see that you are using Grails 2.1.

For others that are getting this error with **Grails 2.2.x** see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19320222/715608)