# Grails 2.2.3 Can't Find Spock on Classpath

Tags: grails, spock

I just added spock to a Grails 2.2.3 project

1. I added the following dependency to **Buildonfig.groovy**:

   ```
   plugins {
       test(":spock:0.7")
   }
   ```
2. Then created my Specification class, **"test/unit/LocationSpec.groovy**:

   ```
   import grails.test.mixin.*

   import org.junit.*

   import spock.lang.*

   /**
    * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
    */
   @TestFor(Location)
   class LocationSpec extends Specification {

       def setup() {
       }

       def cleanup() {
       }

       def "compare"() {
           when:
           def loc1 = new Location(description:descr1)
           def loc2 = new Location(description:descr2)

           then:
           loc1.compareTo(loc2) == descr1.compareTo(descr2)

           where:
           descr1  | descr2    | pidm1     | pidm2
           "foo"   | "foo"     | 1333868   | 1333868
       }
   }
   ```

However I am getting the following errors with the Specification import line:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derp! **R.T.F.M.**

From http://grails.org/plugin/spock:

> Grails 2.2 uses Groovy 2.0, which requires a special Spock
>   version. So to use the Spock plugin with Grails 2.2, modify you
>   BuildConfig.groovy file to include the following:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
  }
  plugins {
    test(":spock:0.7") { exclude "spock-grails-support" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you not found this earlier in doc.

Comment: @Abdullah yep,that's exactly where I found it.  I cited the docs in the answer, and then poked a bit of fun at myself for not following the age old advice: R.T.F.M (Read The Fine Manual) :)